# Add text from Excel to HTML file

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm attempting to add cells from Excel (range c3:c14 in Testimonial_HTML sheet) into a html file and save the file in HTML format.

The code (effectively) inserts the text into the HTML file at line 92, which is exactly where I want it.

The code runs, however, it is not saving in HTML format. It removes some formatting from the original html file. For example it removes commas.

```vb
Public Sub FiletoAppend()

    Dim inFilePath As String
    Dim outFilePath As String
    Dim inFile As Integer
    Dim outFile As Integer
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim fileLine As String

    inFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\testimonia 
    ls.html" ' directory of file to append
    outFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\" & 
    "\MyHTML.html" 'fileName2 = Environ("temp file") & "\MyHTML.html"

    inFile = FreeFile
    Open inFilePath For Input As #inFile
    outFile = FreeFile
    Open outFilePath For Output As #outFile
    lineCount = 0
    Do Until EOF(inFile)
        Line Input #inFile, fileLine
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
        If lineCount < 400 Or lineCount > 401 Then
            Print #outFile, fileLine
        End If
    Loop

    Close #inFile
    Close #outFile

    UpdateHTMLFile

    End Sub


    Sub UpdateHTMLFile()

    ' inserts new Testimonial to testimonials.html file at line 92 *** see 
    below to change line number
    '
    Sheets("Testimonial_HTML").Activate

    Dim line12 As String
    Dim line11 As String
    Dim line10 As String
    Dim line9 As String
    Dim line8 As String
    Dim line7 As String
    Dim line6 As String
    Dim line5 As String
    Dim line4 As String
    Dim line3 As String
    Dim line2 As String
    Dim line1 As String


    Dim MyString As String
    Dim fileName As String, fileName2 As String
    Dim filenum As Long, filenum2 As Long

    Dim i As Long

    fileName2 = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\testimonia 
    ls.html" ' directory of file to append
    fileName = 
    "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\" & 
    "\MyHTML.html" 'fileName2 = Environ("temp") & "\MyHTML.html"


    line1 = Range("c3:c3") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line2 = Range("c4:c4") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line3 = Range("c5:c5") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line4 = Range("c6:c6") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line5 = Range("c7:c7") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line6 = Range("c8:c8") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line7 = Range("c9:c9") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line8 = Range("c10:c10") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line9 = Range("c11:c11") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line10 = Range("c12:c12") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line11 = Range("c13:c13") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from
    line12 = Range("c14:c14") ' the cell that all new jobs are appended to and code copied from

    filenum2 = FreeFile()
    Open fileName2 For Output As #filenum2
    filenum = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input As #filenum
    Do While Not EOF(filenum)

        i = i + 1
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
        l = l + 1
        m = m + 1
        n = n + 1
        o = o + 1
        p = p + 1
        q = q + 1
        r = r + 1
        s = s + 1
        t = t + 1

        Input #filenum, MyString
        Print #filenum2, MyString

        If i = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line1 ' i = the line number in html file
        If j = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line2 ' j = the line number in html file
        If k = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line3 ' k = the line number in html file
        If l = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line4 ' l = the line number in html file
        If m = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line5 ' m = the line number in html file
        If n = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line6 ' n = the line number in html file
        If o = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line7 ' o = the line number in html file
        If p = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line8 ' p = the line number in html file
        If q = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line9 ' q = the line number in html file
        If r = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line10 ' r = the line number in html file
        If s = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line11 ' s = the line number in html file
        If t = 92 Then Print #filenum2, line12 ' t = the line number in html file

    Loop
    Close #filenum
    Close #filenum2

    FileCopy fileName2, fileName
    Kill fileName

End Sub
```

As mentioned the above modules run, however the resulting file is not in HTML format and is missing commas and some other minor formatting.

Comment: Hello Andy, I can't seem to find the `Loop` for your `Do While Not EOF(filenum)` where is it? I'm trying to depurate your code (totally unrelated to your question, but still helpful) and I can't see where does the loop end.

Comment: Hi Damian, not sure what happened there, i somehow deleted loop when pasting code....  Loop goes before the 2 Close lines...5th line from bottom! - updated just now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Joe in this question:
[why does my vba code see comma as new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768000/why-does-my-vba-code-see-comma-as-new-line)

you might want to use
Line Input #filenum, MyString
instead of
Input #filenum, MyString.

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much - it works! Great job responding so quickly - i had done a search but didn't see the post you referenced too!

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a improvement to your code (can't help you with your question) so your code looks better and easier to code:

```
Option Explicit
    Public Sub FiletoAppend()

    Dim inFilePath As String
    Dim outFilePath As String
    Dim inFile As Integer
    Dim outFile As Integer
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim fileLine As String

    inFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\testimonia "
    ls.HTML " ' directory of file to append"
    outFilePath = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\" & _
        "\MyHTML.html" 'fileName2 = Environ("temp file") & "\MyHTML.html"

    inFile = FreeFile
    Open inFilePath For Input As #inFile
    outFile = FreeFile
    Open outFilePath For Output As #outFile
    lineCount = 0
    Do Until EOF(inFile)
        Line Input #inFile, fileLine
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
        If lineCount < 400 Or lineCount > 401 Then
            Print #outFile, fileLine
        End If
    Loop

    Close #inFile
    Close #outFile

    UpdateHTMLFile

    End Sub
Sub UpdateHTMLFile()

    'inserts new Testimonial to testimonials.html file at line 92 *** see
    below to change line number
    '
    Dim Lines(1 To 12) As String
    Dim MyString As String
    Dim fileName As String, fileName2 As String
    Dim filenum As Long, filenum2 As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long

    fileName2 = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\testimonia "
    ls.HTML " ' directory of file to append"
    fileName = "C:\Users\user\Documents\Websites\Clients\AJAYS_WebDesign\joesland\" & _
        "\MyHTML.html" 'fileName2 = Environ("temp") & "\MyHTML.html"

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Testimonial_HTML")
        For i = 1 To 12
            Lines(i) = .Cells(i + 2, 3)
        Next i
    End With

    filenum2 = FreeFile()
    Open fileName2 For Output As #filenum2
    filenum = FreeFile()
    Open fileName For Input As #filenum
    i = 0

    Do While Not EOF(filenum)
        Input #filenum, MyString
        Print #filenum2, MyString
        If i = 92 Then
            For j = 1 To 12
                Print #filenum2, Lines(j)
            Next j
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Close #filenum
    Close #filenum2

    FileCopy fileName2, fileName
    Kill fileName

End Sub
```

Comment: thx Damian - i kinda knew the code wasn't as good as it could be - im pretty much a vba hack but willing to experiment to get a resolution..

Comment: problem fixed above -  Line Input #filenum, MyString instead of Input #filenum, MyString

Comment: Hi Damian, any chance of taking a look at this code - similar to what u cleaned up as above, but this one has 3 lines at different points to insert......Sub

Comment: @AndyWelch that code is ok, except for the `.Activate`thing and so, there is no need for arrays or loops because there are only 3 items and with no correlation. So you should only adjust the code to avoid using the `.Activate` like I did in my code.